# Alternative to HandleRef in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

What is an alternative to `HandleRef` in Silverlight, I have a Silverlight Class Library with 1460 errors depending on this, what could replace it, some of usages

```
HandleRef(this, cPtr);
HandleRef(null, IntPtr.Zero);
private HandleRef cPtr;
```